# Bluetooth pairing without using bluetoothctl

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I am currently trying to pair my Android phone with my Raspberry Pi without using the command line. 
I found several solutions, but none worked for me.

My aim is, that bluetooth devices can connect to my Raspberry using a hardcoded Bluetooth Passkey, so that the Raspberry automaticly accepts this connection.

Best regards